# Display Time in AM PM from Model with DataAnnotations

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display a Sql Server time field in AM and PM. It displays correcly in edit mode but not in list mode.
Model:

```
    public class HMSappointmentMetaData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Rep Name is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 50")]
    public string Rep { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Customer Name is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 50")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 100")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 50")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Zip is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 50")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "County is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 50")]
    public string County { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Home Phone is required")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 10")]
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mobile Phone is required")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 10")]
    public string CellPhone { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Question is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 50")]
    public string OwnHome { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Question is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 50")]
    public string HaveAttic { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Question is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 50")]
    public string AvgElectric { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Question is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 50")]
    public string SummerSpike { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Question is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 50")]
    public string TriedAny { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Question is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 50")]
    public string InsulationType { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Question is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 50")]
    public string InsulationAge { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Question is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 50")]
    public string LastPaint { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Question is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 50")]
    public string Married { get; set; }
    public string Spouse { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Occupation is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Max length is 50")]
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public string SpouseJob { get; set; }
    public string RetireFrom { get; set; }
    public string SpouseRetireFrom { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Appointment Date is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Appointment Time is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> Time { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm tt}")]
    public System.TimeSpan? TimeForDisplay { get { return (Time.HasValue) ? (System.TimeSpan?)DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Add(Time.Value) : null; } }
    public HMSappointmentMetaData()
    {
        Time = new TimeSpan(14,30,0);
    }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string CreditScore { get; set; }
}
```

List View:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Time)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TimeForDisplay)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Notes", "Index", "AdminNotes", new { AppointmentID = item.ID }, null) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

This results in 24 hr time (14:30)

Edit View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Time)
```

This displays the correctly formatted time(2:30 PM).

Comment: Did the answer help you anyway.?

Comment: change line @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TimeForDisplay) to @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.TimeForDisplay) as it is inside for loop, you have to use that instance of item, not the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its not ideal but without little bit of extra work I could not get it working so here are the options

**Option 1**

Use a DisplayTemplate and format manually.

**Option 2** -- I like this better.

Add this new property to your ViewModel

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm tt}")]
public DateTime? TimeForDisplay 
{
  get { return (Time.HasValue)? (DateTime?)DateTime.Today.Add(Time.Value):null;}
}
```

use this new Property for Display Only in the view as follows

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TimeForDisplay)
```

Here is the Demo **[Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TBUome)**

Comment: I got the following error message:  CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<GCadmin.Models.HMSappointmentVM>' does not contain a definition for 'TimeForDisplay' and no extension method 'TimeForDisplay' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<GCadmin.Models.HMSappointmentVM>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: don't forget to add this new property to your ViewModel 'public DateTime? TimeForDisplay' as indicated above in the answer

Comment: I did         [Required(ErrorMessage = "Appointment Time is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> Time { get; set; }
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm tt}")]
        public DateTime? TimeForDisplay { get { return (Time.HasValue) ? (DateTime?)DateTime.Today.Add(Time.Value) : null; } }

Comment: As you can see Demo link, it works , you have a different issue, Can you post your viewmodel and view code to this question or new question.

Comment: as this property is added to HMSAppointmentVM, you may either have a DisplayTemplate or for loop to display this, Incase of for loop to display item, change the line '@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TimeForDisplay)' accordingly

Comment: I have changed the original post to include the changes.

Comment: Change line @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TimeForDisplay) to @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.TimeForDisplay) as it is inside for loop, you have to use that instance of item, not the model

Comment: Still getting GCadmin.Models.HMSappointment' does not contain a definition for 'TimeForDisplay' and no extension method 'TimeForDisplay' accepting a first argument of type 'GCadmin.Models.HMSappointment' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please change it @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.TimeForDisplay), NOT NOT @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TimeForDisplay)

Comment: If it answers you question, you should accept it as answer.

Comment: Sorry, I got sidetracked, I will try it and mark as answer if it works. Thx Doug